# Replacing a huge dump file with an efficient lookup Java key-value text store

Tags: java, large-files, key-value-store

I have a huge dump file - 12GB of text containing millions of entries. Each entry has a numeric id, some text, and other irrelevant properties. I want to convert this file into something that will provide an efficient look-up. That is, given an id, it would return the text quickly. The limitations:

1. Embedded in Java, preferably without an external server or foreign language dependencies.
2. Read and writes to the disk, not in-memory - I don't have 12GB of RAM.
3. Does not blow up too much - I don't want to turn a 12GB file into a 200GB index. I don't need full text search, sorting, or anything fancy - Just key-value lookup.
4. Efficient - It's a lot of data and I have just one machine, so speed is an issue. Tools that can store large batches and/or work well with several threads are preferred.
5. Storing more than one field is nice, but not a must. The main concern is the text.

Your recommendations are welcomed!

Comment: You should specify the format of your dump.

Comment: Does the format matter ? It sounds like it needs to be loaded into some store, and consequently the initial format is not relevant for this question

Comment: @BrianAgnew I was thinking if one line per record, he could create a manual index `id=>lineNumber`

Comment: @RC Some trivial XML where each entry is a single tag. However, a fully-featured XML DB would be an overkill because it does not have any hierarchical structure. It might have been CSV and the problem would remain the same.

Comment: @RC using the line number instead of the given id is an interesting idea: how fast is Java in fetching a single line out of a 12GB-sized file? I'm not sure I can use this trick alone, though, because there are some cross-references.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables don't know, it was just a "crazy idea"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [JavaDb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) - the db that comes with Java ?

It'll store the info on disk, and be efficient in terms of lookups, provided you index properly. It'll run in-JVM, so you don't need a separate server/service. You talk to it using standard JDBC.

I suspect it'll be pretty efficient. This database has a long history (it used to be IBM's Derby) and will have had a lot of effort expended on it in terms of robustness and efficiency.

You'll obviously need to do an initial onboarding of the data to create the database, but that's a one-off task.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) or something like it (partly because I wrote it) because it is designed to access large amounts of data (larger than your machine) some what randomly.

It can store any number of fields in text or binary formats (or a combination if you wish)  It adds 8 bytes per record you want to be able to randomly access. It doesn't support deleting records (you can mark them for reuse), but you can update and add new records.

It can only have a single writer thread, but it can be read by an number of threads on the same machine (even different processes)

It doesn't support batching but it can read/write millions of entries per second with typical sub microsecond latency (except for random reads/writes which are not in memory)

It uses next to no heap (<1 MB for TBs of data)

It uses an id which is sequential but you can build a table to do just that translation.

BTW: You can buy 32 GB for less than $200. Perhaps its time to get more memory ;)

Comment: Does Chronicle in-memory or caches to disk?

Comment: It uses memory mapped files so the disk cache of the OS is accessible directly in Java. It means reading and writing to disk is done transparently by the OS. i.e. how much is in memory and how is on disk does matter so much (in fact it's not possible to tell from Java) and depends on how much free resources you have. BTW It requires a 64-bit JVM to be useful as it uses virtual memory.